# Checking checkboxes from colon-delimited string

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Our online form receives a colon-delimited string from the database for one of our fields. For example, we have a checkbox group called "Favorite Fruits", which contains eight checkboxes:

```
 Apples - AP
 Bananas - BA
 Blueberries - BL
 Cherries - CH
 Grapes - GR
 Oranges - OR
 Raspberries - RA
 Strawberries - ST
```

Let's say a user submits a form with three checkboxes checked: Cherries, Grapes and Strawberries. When users submit the form, the 'fruits' field receives the following: CH,GR,ST. When the user revisits the page, instead of comma-separated, it's received like this CH::GR::ST. For this example, I'm trying to figure out how to check the checkboxes so that Cherries, Grapes and Strawberries are checked on page load.

Here's what I have so far:

```
   <div id='fruits'>
    <input type='checkbox' id='AP' value='Apples' />Apples<br />
    <input type='checkbox' id='BA' value='Bananas' />Bananas<br />
    <input type='checkbox' id='BL' value='Blueberries' />Blueberries<br />
    <input type='checkbox' id='CH' value='Cherries' />Cherries<br />
    <input type='checkbox' id='GR' value='Grapes' />Grapes<br />
    <input type='checkbox' id='OR' value='Oranges' />Oranges<br />
    <input type='checkbox' id='RA' value='Raspberries' />Raspberries<br />
    <input type='checkbox' id='ST' value='Strawberries' />Strawberries<br />
   </div> 

    var faveFruits = ['CH','GR','ST'];

    $("#fruits").find('[id=' + faveFruits.join('], [id=') + ']').prop("checked", true);
```

That works fine, because of the way the faveFruits variable/array is defined. It actually loads on the page like this:

```
    var faveFruits = CH::GR::ST
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Codewalker/mw9746pq/12/

Comment: `faveFruits.split("::")`

Comment: I hope it loads like `var faveFruits = "CH::GR::ST"`

Comment: Yes, it loads like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) in order to build up the selector:

```
faveFruits.reduce((a,e,idx,arr) => a+='#' + e + (idx+1 == arr.length ? '' : ', '), '')
```

The result of previous line is: #CH, #GR, #ST

Because you are selecting by id you can address directly them without using the parent element **fruits**.

If the input string is:

```
 var faveFruits = "CH::GR::ST";
```

you can apply a split plus reduce:

```
var selector = faveFruits.split('::').reduce((a,e,idx,arr) => a+='#' + e + (idx+1 == arr.length ? '' : ', '), '')
```

```js
var faveFruits = ['CH','GR','ST'];


var selector = faveFruits.reduce((a,e,idx,arr) => a+='#' + e + (idx+1 == arr.length ? '' : ', '), '');
console.log(selector);

$(selector).prop("checked", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id='fruits'>
    <input type='checkbox' id='AP' value='Apples' />Apples<br />
    <input type='checkbox' id='BA' value='Bananas' />Bananas<br />
    <input type='checkbox' id='BL' value='Blueberries' />Blueberries<br />
    <input type='checkbox' id='CH' value='Cherries' />Cherries<br />
    <input type='checkbox' id='GR' value='Grapes' />Grapes<br />
    <input type='checkbox' id='OR' value='Oranges' />Oranges<br />
    <input type='checkbox' id='RA' value='Raspberries' />Raspberries<br />
    <input type='checkbox' id='ST' value='Strawberries' />Strawberries<br />
</div>
```